# Json Array to Map using JsonSlurper

Tags: json, groovy

I want to create a map of data with the pid value as the key and the name as the array for a json array.  Here is the json structure:

```
{
"measurements": [
    {
        "pid": 6691,
        "name": "lung",
        "measurement": "qualityFactor",
    },
    {
        "pid": 1106,
        "name": "kidney",
        "measurement": "qualityFactor",
    },
    {
        "id": 119,
        "name": "pancreas",
        "measurement": "qualityFactor",
    },

]
```

}

Here is my attempt with Groovy but I'm stuck:

```
    def jsonSlurper= new JsonSlurper()
    Object objs=jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonData) 
    List pp =objs.data 
    Map<String,String> m=new HashMap()
    pp.each{ it ->
        it.collect{Map mm ->
            println "Map m is ${mm}"

        }
    }
```

I want the map to look like
["6691" : "lung" , "1106" :"kidney" ....] etc.

Hiw can I accomplish this?

Comment: `measurements.collectEntries{ [it.pid, it.name ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a full answer with corrected JSON:

```
def json = '''{
    "measurements": [
        {
            "pid": 6691,
            "name": "lung",
            "measurement": "qualityFactor",
        },
        {
            "pid": 1106,
            "name": "kidney",
            "measurement": "qualityFactor",
        },
        {
            "pid": 119,
            "name": "pancreas",
            "measurement": "qualityFactor",
        }
    ]
}
'''

import groovy.json.*

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def map = map.measurements.collectEntries { [it.pid.toString(), it.name] }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!   A really instructive solution